# Are "strings.xml" string arrays always parsed/deserialized in the same order?

Tags: android, xml, deserialization, arrays, android-resources

Can I count on string arrays within the "strings.xml" resource file to be parsed/deserialized in the same order ***every time***?

If anyone can cite any documentation that clearly spells out this guarantee, I'd appreciate it.  Or, at the very least, offer a significant amount of experience with this topic.

Also, is this a best practice or am I missing a simpler solution?

**Note:** This will be a small list, so I'm not looking to implement a more complicated database or custom XML solution unless I absolutely have to.

```
<!--KEYS (ALWAYS CORRESPONDS TO LIST BELOW ??)-->
<string-array name="keys">
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
</string-array>

<!--VALUES (ALWAYS CORRESPONDS TO LIST ABOVE ??)-->
<string-array name="values">
    <item>one</item>
    <item>two</item>
    <item>three</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: The question is difficult to understand. string-arrays do not belong to string.xml but rather values.xml. The correspondence, if any, is defined by the programmer. What is the task you want to achieve?

Comment: I don't have a "values.xml" file.  All of my resources are defined in the "strings.xml" file within the "res/values" folder.  This works just fine.  What I'm trying to determine is if I can count on the key/value pairs always aligning (1/one, 2/two, 3/three, etc.).  I don't want to build logic around this if the deserialization of the "item" nodes is performed randomly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as far as I'm aware you can assume that the order of items will be the same each time, meaning you can safely define key/value pairs using separately xml-declared arrays. Have a look at the API demos (e.g. the [`arrays.xml`](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/res/values/arrays.html) file) and you'll see that Google uses the same methodoly to specify static key/value pairs. More specifically, you'll be able to deduce this from `entries_list_preference` and `entryvalues_list_preference`. Actually, if you think about it: it would hardly make sense to offer `entries` and `entryValues` attributes for pointing to static resources for e.g. a `ListPreference` if their order wouldn't be guaranteed.

Addendum: Multi-dimensional arrays in xml are not supported. You can however write your own xml parser to handle those cases, which actually isn't as hard as it may sound. It would probably take you more time though than simply defining two one-dimensional arrays.