# Sorting string-array

Tags: android, arrays, sorting

I have string-array of profession in my values/strings.xml.I want to sort the array in alphabetical order.How can i achieve it.

Strings.Xml

```
<string-array name="Profession">

        <item>Caretaker</item>
        <item>Cook</item>
        <item>Driver</item>
        <item>Governess</item>
        <item>HouseKeeper</item>
        <item>Maid</item>
        <item>Watchman</item>
        <item>Washerman</item>
        <item>Paper Supplier</item>
        <item>Milkman</item>
        <item>Electrician</item>
        <item>Ration Supplier</item>
        <item>Gas Supplier</item>
        <item>Volunteer</item>
        <item>Nurse</item>
        <item>Other</item>
        <item>Carpenter</item>
        <item>Plumber</item>
        <item>Mason</item>
        <item>Delivery Boy</item>
        <item>Gardner</item>
        <item>Janitor</item>
        <item>Launderer</item>
        <item>Dhobi/Press</item>
        <item>Odd Jobs</item>
        <item>Vendor</item>
        <item>Shopkeeper </item>

    </string-array>
```

Comment: see `Arrays.sort()`...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039258/are-strings-xml-string-arrays-always-parsed-deserialized-in-the-same-order

Comment: Isn't it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891732/sort-android-strings-xml-in-alphabetical-order

Comment: put sorted array in strings.xml

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
String[] list = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Profession); 

Arrays.sort(list);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this to sort your Arrays.

```
Collections.sort(Your_Array)
```

Answer (score 3):

Get the array into an `ArrayList` like

```
String[] professionArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.Profession);
ArrayList<String> professionArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(professionArray));
```

and then sort it using

```
Collections.sort(professionArrayList);
```